# How to change font size of axes labels without affecting everything else in a framed plot

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have a plot expression that looks something like this:

```
LogPlot[
 {f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 1000},
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
 FrameLabel -> {"x axis", "y axis"},
 FrameTicks -> {
   Automatic,
   Table[{10^i, Superscript["10", ToString[i]]}, {i, 2, 6}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"f(x)", "g(x)"}, {.2, .8}]
]
```

I want to increase the size of the axes labels *without changing the size of the tick labels or the legends*. The only advice I can find on this issue doesn't seem to work when using a Frame. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

### Example

**Description**

Use `Style` to format the text. I also didn't include the output of your `LogPlot` due to being unaware of your `f[x]` and `g[x]` definitions.

**Code**

```
Plot[
 Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 AxesLabel -> {Style["x", Bold, 16], Style["Sin(x)", Bold, 16]}
]
```

in your case

```
LogPlot[
 {f[x], g[x]},
 {x, 0, 1000},
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
 FrameLabel -> {Style["x axis", 16, Bold], Style["y axis", 16, Bold]},
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, Table[{10^i, Superscript["10", ToString[i]]}, {i, 2, 6}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"f(x)", "g(x)"}, {.2, .8}]
 ]
```

**Output**

[image: example]

**Reference**

[Style](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html)
[AxesLabel](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesLabel.html?q=AxesLabel)

Comment: The following is really a question of style, so please feel free to ignore me if you disagree: however, I would find your answer more readable if it had less fragmentation, and if it stated the approach you took to solve the problem right at the beginning, rather than burying it in a note. Regarding fragmentation, I mean to say that having section headers for such a short answer seems overkill and it obfuscates your point. (but +1 for the workaround!)

Comment: @MarcoB thank you for your input on this matter. I try to maintain uniform look and feel to the answers I leave here on Mathematica.SE. I would most definitely take on your advise regarding moving the approach taken to solve the problem at the begining of the answer and leave notes for any additional information that I might have

Comment: Absolutely! As I said, this is really only a matter of my personal preference, so please feel free to disregard! Anyway, thanks for moving the explanation to the top: it enhances readability in my opinion.

Comment: I appreciate any input on the answers I leave; I find it beneficial and it allows me to imrpove the quality of my answers as I go. So I thank you for that!